# Camera recording time paradox

Tags: project-almanac

When David and Chris first found their dad's old camera (CAM-1) in the attic in *Project Almanac*, Chris leaves her "present and modern camera" on the table to record themselves while watching what was recorded in CAM-1

The rest of the movie happens...

At the end, the same scene takes place, but now they've found a second camera (CAM-2) and that camera had recorded both of them finding the first one.

How could that second camera had recorded that?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie yet, but sounds a lot like both cameras were simply the same? What happens with the first camera after finding it?